# Update activity column with descriptions

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

STUDENT ACTIVITY table:

```
ID  NAME    TIME_FROM   TIME_TO    ACTIVITY
-------------------------------------------
1   ABC      9:00        10:00     WALK
2   ABC      10:00       12:00     PLAY

GAMELOG table:

ID ACTIVITY_ID   STUDENT_NAME  CRICKET (HR)   FOOT BALL (HR)
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    2            ABC              1               1
```

Student Activity table has student main activity and gamelog table contains the activities in details. For Ex: activity "PLAY" includes CRICKET and FOOT BALL as details of the activity.

I need a query to retrieve activity details as shown in expected output:

```
ID  NAME    ACTIVITY    DURATION HOURS  
----------------------------------------
1   ABC     WALKING          1  
2   ABC     CRICKET          1  
2   ABC     FOOTBALL         1
```

If there is no detailed activity for a main activity as shown above for WALKING, the query should return the main activity

Assume game log is generated based on time logged. The student walked for an hour and played for 2 hrs The play details are being logged in detail as cricket 1 hr and foot ball 1 hr

Game order should be 1. CRICKET AND 2. FOOT BALL

To be simple, whenever there is a column value PLAY, the out put should display the play details from the GameLog table with CRICKET and FOOT BALL TIME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Pivoting the Gamelog first as CTE or temp table based on your choice

```
with game_cte as
Select 
    id
    ,activity_id
    ,Student_Name
    ,'Cricket' as Activity
    ,cricket_hr as duration
    ,'Play' as action
from
    gamelog
where
    cricket_hr > 0

UNION ALL

Select 
    id
    ,activity_id
    ,Student_Name
    ,'Football' as Activity
    ,football_hr as duration
    ,'Play' as action
from
    gamelog
where
    football_hr > 0
```

Then try this union

```
SELECT 
    G.activity_id
    ,G.Name
    ,G.Activity
    ,G.duration
FROM 
    Student_Activity SA 
    JOIN game_cte G ON SA.Name = G.Student_Name and SA.activity = G.action

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    S.ID
    ,S.Name
    ,CASE 
        WHEN S.Activity = 'WALK' THEN 'Walking'
     END CASE AS Activity
    ,(time_to - time_from) as duration
FROM 
    Student_Activity SA 
    JOIN GameLog G ON SA.Name = G.Student_Name
WHERE
    sa.activity = 'Walk'
```

Try whether this helps..

Comment: I'm glad answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried without actually creating tables.. hope it helps.

```
SELECT 
    S.ID
    ,S.Name
    ,CASE 
        WHEN S.Activity = 'WALK' THEN 'Walking'
        WHEN A.Cricket = 1 AND S.Activity = 'Play' THEN 'Cricket'
        WHEN A.Football = 1 AND S.Activity = 'Play' THEN 'Football'
    END CASE AS Activity
FROM 
    Student_Activity SA 
    JOIN GameLog G ON SA.Name = G.Student_Name
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Thanks for the answer but the Cricket and Foot ball hrs may vary so it is not always 1 and I need both Cricket and Foot Ball values whenever Activity has value "PLAY"